# SPF Record with or without plus

Tags: spf

Is there any difference between

```
v=spf1 +a +mx -all
```

and

```
v=spf1 a mx -all
```

I am unsure if they do the same thing or somthing different. Clarification would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, yes, there is a difference.

According to the [SPF Record Syntax](http://www.open-spf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax/), **a plus sign** (+) indicates that the record should pass, no questions asked.

The **absence of a plus sign**, or the inclusion of a question mark (?) indicates **neutral status** — the domain owner is not offering an opinion about whether the message should pass.

However, the end result is (almost) always the same: the email will pass.

Comment: The default identifier is + so they have the same outcome, just the intent is more obvious when using the first notation.  I guess someone could override the default interpretation by their SPF setup (whoever manages the server receiving mails), but it seems unlikely.

Comment: From the page you reference: `The default qualifier is "+"`, so no qualifier is the same as "+". It is **not** the same as a "?", and nowhere on that page is something like that mentioned. If SPF on the whole can't come up with a match then a "neutral" result is returned, but that's not the same as a mechanism qualifier.

Comment: Good grief... Yes, you're right. But if you look further down, it says this: "Mechanisms are evaluated in order. If no mechanism or modifier matches, the default result is 'Neutral'." I give up trying to be helpful on serverfault (not really, but this is frustrating).

Comment: DavidW, I think that I see your point.  I stipulate that you've given an excellent and accurate answer to the question "*What happens if I have a completely blank SPF record, or it contains only mechanisms that cannot ever match?*", and I have to admit, I've wondered about that myself - and now will wonder no more.  Sadly, the OP didn't ask that question.

Comment: I'll upvote that. :)

Comment: I dont know who to upvote so I'm upvoting you all

Answer (score 15):

[The SPF record syntax summary](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax), right at the top, states that

> If a mechanism results in a hit, its qualifier value is used. The
>   default qualifier is "+", i.e. "Pass".

So it seems clear to me that there's no technical difference between `mx` and `+mx`.

Comment: Well, I think we're talking semantics. I see a slight difference, but I'm a stickler for grammar and clarification. =) In reality, there's no difference at all (or at least shouldn't be), unless a receiving mail server admin has a misconfigured server.

Comment: David, it's not a semantic issue.  You said that "The absence of a plus sign, or the inclusion of a question mark (?) indicates a "neutral" status".  The first half of that is simply wrong; the standard is clear that absence of any sign indicates a plus sign.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. It has clarified that the difference is so small that is doesn't really matter which one you put. However I have decided to add the + to the records as the plus mean pass.

Comment: As does no plus - that's the point of my answer.  **There is no difference**, DavidW's misunderstanding notwithstanding.